# Sails.js Policy Not Redirecting

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I have the default sessionAuth policy as follows

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.session.authenticated) {
      return next();
    }
    return res.redirect('login');
};
```

...and my routes as:

```
'GET /' : '/login',
'GET /login' : {view : 'login'},
'POST /dashboard/login' : 'DashboardController.login',
'GET /dashboard' : { view : 'dashboard/overview'},
```

My app is still allowing me to view my view undefined without redirecting me. I have Angular modules making requests to the DashboardController and they don't even trigger the redirect.

I have tried adding an index function for '*' path which works, but removes all my CSS from my login view.

Comment: Look into AJAX calls and redirect. If Angular is managing view, how should server do the redirect. Without angular your code looks fine.

Comment: I am using angular $http to make my requests. Should I redirect after a bad response?

Comment: One way would be to send `401 unauthorized` status and Angular app goes to login route. One doubt though: As you are using Angular, why do you have login view in Sails app?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I made myself clear. I'm using Angular to get and display data from my sails app within the site.

Comment: But this route `'GET /login' : {view : 'login'},` suggests your `/login` is rendered by Sails, not Angular. Same for `/dashboard`

Comment: Yes, that is true. However, Angular is only being used once the user has access to the dashboard. Nothing fires as intended if the user isn't logged in. What I can't get my head around is why the redirect is not working through the policy.

Comment: I think it is because the request which is redirected is AJAX request, not normal browser one. If it is, you can either read `401` status in Angular and redirect OR look into redirection with AJAX.

Comment: I see, I will try that approach now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: DId you remember about adding policy into ```config/policies.js```?

Comment: I think @Bonanza is right, where is the reference to this being applies in policies.js?